# best codeigniter 2.1 authentication library with social networking site integration

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, codeigniter-a3m

What's the best codeigniter authentication library out there that supports social networking integration such as `facebook, twitter, linkedin, google+` etc?

Currently I'm learning a3m which is ok, but I'm having some troubles integrating it to twitter because they have updated their API.

I found tank while googling around but I haven't tried it yet. I found some other authentication library but they lack documentation which I'm having a hard time learning. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved my problem in twitter for a3m. I just have to supply my callback url with the correct path.

something like this.

```
$callback_url = http://mywebsite.com/somephpfile.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I've started developing a Codeigniter library for making oAuth requests to Twitter.  [The source code can be found here.](https://github.com/pattle/codeigniter-twitter-library)

Comment: I was kinda looking for multiple site authentication library. Thanks for sharing anyway. :)